# Symfony 4 serialize API response

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

i am developing a Symfony 4 application that will serve some APIs to a frontend Redux application.

The frontend team asked me a particular structure of the response that is the following:

```
[
    {
        id: "ec13522c-7124-4f35-955a-7d1fdff980ba",
        name: "Test",
        created: "Fri, 15 Jun 2018 14:39:08 +0200",
        updated: "Fri, 15 Jun 2018 18:03:32 +0200",
        relation1: [
            "ada90e5e-e678-41dc-91d5-d28eb5ab222f",
            "af7fef3a-5681-4f22-bc55-c759df9074f5",
            "66dab1aa-212f-4dba-b2ee-93fe7d850c8d",
            "8fcf1cb5-450a-40bc-af3f-6d40c6085f8e"
        ],
        relation2: [
            "f20e2bbe-8542-43d7-8ccb-92513ac88a35"
        ]
    }
]
```

Where the external relations of this object are represented as an array of Ids useful to fetch their data.

With Symfony i built a serializer using circular references to resolve external relations

```
static function serializeResponse($data) {
    $encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];
    $normalizer = new GetSetMethodNormalizer();
    // Avoiding circular references on foreign keys
    $normalizer->setCircularReferenceLimit(1);
    $normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object) {
        return $object->getId();
    });
    // DateTime custom normalizer
    $callbackDate = function ($dateTime) {
        return $dateTime instanceof \DateTime
            ? $dateTime->format(\DateTime::RFC1123)
            : '';
    };
    $normalizer->setCallbacks(['created' => $callbackDate, 'updated' => $callbackDate]);
    $serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer], $encoders);

    $serializedData = $serializer->serialize($data, 'json');
    return $serializedData;
}
```

But the response that i obtain is obviously different:

```
[
    {
        id: "ec13522c-7124-4f35-955a-7d1fdff980ba",
        name: "Test",
        created: "Fri, 15 Jun 2018 14:39:08 +0200",
        updated: "Fri, 15 Jun 2018 18:03:32 +0200",
        relation1: [
            {
                id: "f20e2bbe-8542-43d7-8ccb-92513ac88a35",
                name: "Name1"
            }
        ],
        relation2: [
            {
                id: "ada90e5e-e678-41dc-91d5-d28eb5ab222f",
                name: "name2",
                created: "Fri, 15 Jun 2018 18:39:45 +0200",
                updated: "Fri, 15 Jun 2018 18:39:45 +0200",
                relation3: [
                    {
                        id: "15a9fd25-fcb4-404d-8d39-6c06569c58ab",
                        element: "TextElement1",
                        relation2: "ada90e5e-e678-41dc-91d5-d28eb5ab222f",
                        relation1: {
                            id: "5427af08-1185-4bda-8ec9-c4e9c3219d61",
                            name: "Name1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        id: "389779bb-630a-45b1-9923-ca717b6b26f5",
                        element: "TextElement2",
                        relation2: "ada90e5e-e678-41dc-91d5-d28eb5ab222f",
                        relation3: {
                            id: "f20e2bbe-8542-43d7-8ccb-92513ac88a35",
                            name: "Name1"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                relation: "ec13522c-7124-4f35-955a-7d1fdff980ba"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

At the moment i am not using the serializer showed before but i built a custom function that purpose is to fetch and refactor the entities to create the wanted response.

Is there a way to achieve the same goal using Symfony functions maybe to return only IDs of external relations as array? I tried with the notation @group but this will just reduce the number of elements retrieved without reformatting them.

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Normalizer should do the job.

Comment: Hi, can you explain a little more?

Comment: sorry i was on my phone, you should read this [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html). you'll probably find a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) you've some examples about **normalizer**.
Here is an [example with date formatting](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#using-callbacks-to-serialize-properties-with-object-instances).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you, i used this documentation to implement the dateTime formatting that i am using but when i tried to apply a callback to an external entity the callback is fired before the relation is resolved so i am not able to apply it on the ArrayCollection